# Closing connections to prevent leaks in Java/ADF

Tags: java, oracle-adf

we noticed our application was having connection leaks due to open connections. The source of most was the code further down coming from JSFUtil and ADFUtil classes. I cannot identify which variable/method should I use to close the connection.

To call this method we create an ApplicationModuleImplementation object that calls the ADFUtil method, which in turn calls JSFUtil. I tried several methods to close the AMImpl object but none prevent the leak.

Methods I've tried: amImpl.remove(), amImpl.reset(), amImpl.resetState(true/false).

```
/**
 * Method for taking a reference to a JSF binding expression and returning
 * the matching object (or creating it).
 * @param expression
 * @return Managed object
 */
public static Object resolveExpression(String expression) {
    FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    Application app = ctx.getApplication();
    ValueBinding bind = app.createValueBinding(expression);
    return bind.getValue(ctx);
}


/**
 * Get application module for an application module data control by name.
 * @param name application module data control name
 * @return ApplicationModule
 */
public static ApplicationModule getApplicationModuleForDataControl(String name) {
    return (ApplicationModule)JSFUtils.resolveExpression("#{data." + name +
                                                         ".dataProvider}");
}


//CALL TO ABOVE
 am = ADFUtils.getApplicationModuleForDataControl("NAME");
```

Comment: The issue could not be about your ADFUtil but in your AM configuration. You need to go to your AM > Configurations > EDIT and update the properties : Idle Instance Timeout / jbo.ampool.maxinactiveage / timetolive / ...

Comment: Also what are you using your AM for ? Are you doing something like : am.getDBTransaction().createCallableStatement(...). ?

Comment: Hi, I am using Application Modules to get System Profile Options for View Objects Implementations. So this issue could be solved by editing server options rather than coding?

Comment: It depends, if you do a am.getDBTransaction() at some point then you need to close it in the code. If the leak comes only from the AM you'll have to play with the AM configuration to test why.